# serial communication in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, serial-port

I'm working on my very first app. This app is to communicate with external hardware using a cable I got from RedPark.
They provide a library which has several functions easy to use. 
Now I need to require a 9*9 table with float number in it by sending a command to ask for it.

A function called (void)readBytesAvailable is used for read, and it's event driven.
At first, I used a NSMutableArray to put the table:

```
    for (int i=0; i<81; i++) {
        NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:rxLoopBuffer[i]];
        [self.arrayRead addObject:number];
        NSLog(@"%f",[number doubleValue]);
    }
```

but from the console, it only got 11 numbers, and the rest 70 are all 0s.
I thought maybe I need to get all 81 bytes first, then push them into array, so I did some changes:

```
    NSMutableData *dataRead = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithBytes:&rxLoopBuff length:81];
    unsigned char buffer[100];
    [dataRead getBytes:buffer];
    if (!self.arrayRead) {
    [self.arrayRead removeAllObjects];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<81; i++) {
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:buffer[i]];
    [self.arrayRead addObject:number];
    NSLog(@"%f",[number doubleValue]);
    }
```

But it still gets 11 numbers.

Can anyone give me some advices on this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Update:
By debugging, I saw the read method only reads 16 bytes max at a time. I'm downloading a new version library provided by same company to see what I can do.
The part of method code:

```
    - (void) readBytesAvailable:(UInt32)numBytes
   {
    int bytesRead; 
    BOOL res = NO;

// Read the data out
bytesRead = [rscMgr read:(rxLoopBuff+loopbackCount) length:numBytes];
rxCount += bytesRead;

    //NSLog(@"Read %i, total=%i\n", bytesRead, rxCount);
    if (this is the package I need)
    {
       //do something;
    }

   }
```

Comment: How do you fill `rxLoopBuff`? Where's the code which communicates with serial port? This code just reads `rxLoopBuff` and creates numbers from buffer.

Comment: Are you certain that all the data is being transmitted in the same packet? My first assumption would be that, or that all the data simply isn't being transmitted. Id try connecting the cable to a computer and using a simple terminal program to see if you get the same results.

Comment: @RobertVojta Hi, from what I understand rxLoopBuff is filled itself. When there is data coming in readBytesAvailable is automatically called. But your comment did remind me. So I print out all the bytes I receive and the count each time, turns out I only received max 16 bytes each time, sometimes 3 or 7. I put the code in my post.

Comment: Nothing is filled by itself :) What library do you use?

Comment: @BrianV, I'm sure the data was sent and was in one packet, but I just found out(by debug, I don't the if it's true), the read method only reads 16bytes max each time. So I'm downloading a new version library provided by that company see what I can do about it. I also post the part code of read method.

Comment: @RobertVojta I'm using a library called libRscMgrUniv.a  [redpark](http://www.redpark.com/c2db9_FAQs.html) Here is the website for requesting download.

Comment: Will download it and check it ...

Answer (score 0):

*DISCLAIMER - I don't have this cable, so, I can't test it and maybe the code doesn't work. But it's just blind demonstration how would I do it. It's ARC enabled code.*

**SerialPortCommunication.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SerialPortCommunication : NSObject

- (void)readBytes:(UInt32)numberOfBytes
          success:(void(^)( NSData *data ))success
          failure:(void(^)( NSData *dataReadSoFar, NSError *error ))failure;

@end
```

**SerialPortCommunication.m**

```
#import "SerialPortCommunication.h"
#import "RscMgr.h"

#define BUFFER_SIZE 128

@interface SerialPortCommunication() < RscMgrDelegate > {
  RscMgr *_rscMgr;           // Resource Manager
  BOOL _portAvailable;       // Can we use port?
  NSMutableData *_data;      // Buffer for data
  UInt32 _totalBytesToRead;  // Number of total bytes to read

  // Success block to call
  void(^ _successBlock )( NSData *data );

  // Failure block to call
  void(^ _failureBlock )( NSData *dataReadSoFar, NSError *error );

  UInt8 *_buffer;
}

@end

@implementation SerialPortCommunication

#pragma mark - Lifecycle

- (void)dealloc {
  free( _buffer );
}

- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if ( self ) {
    _rscMgr = [[RscMgr alloc] init];
    [_rscMgr setDelegate:self];

    _buffer = malloc( BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof( UInt8 ) );
    // DO SERIAL PORT CONFIGURATION HERE
  }
  return self;
}

#pragma mark - Public

- (void)readBytes:(UInt32)numberOfBytes
          success:(void(^)( NSData *data ))success
          failure:(void(^)( NSData *dataReadSoFar, NSError *error ))failure {
  if ( ! _portAvailable ) {
    if ( failure ) {
      // Create some NSError that port is not available
      failure( nil, nil );
      return;
    }
  }

  if ( _data ) {
    if ( failure ) {
      // Create some NSError that port is in use
      failure( nil, nil );
      return;
    }
  }

  _failureBlock = failure;
  _successBlock = success;
  _totalBytesToRead = numberOfBytes;

  _data = [NSMutableData data];
  // Now we're waiting for delegate methods
}

#pragma mark - RscMgrDelegate

- (void)cableConnected:(NSString *)protocol {
  // From now on you can use serial port
  _portAvailable = YES;
  [_rscMgr open];
}

- (void)cableDisconnected {
  // From now on you can't user serial port
  _portAvailable = NO;

  // Ouch, we can't read, fire failure
  if ( _failureBlock ) {
    // Create NSError which describes cable disconnection
    _failureBlock( _data, nil );
  }

  // Our task ends here
  _successBlock = nil;
  _failureBlock = nil;
  _data = nil;
  _totalBytesToRead = 0;
}

- (void)portStatusChanged {
  // Check status if everything's alright and you can still user serial port
  // Set _portAvailable accordingly

  // Replace if ( NO ) with condition if port is still alright and we can read
  if ( NO ) {
    if ( _failureBlock ) {
      // Create NSError which describes status change and we can't use serial port
      _failureBlock( _data, nil );
    }

    // Our task ends here
    _successBlock = nil;
    _failureBlock = nil;
    _data = nil;
    _totalBytesToRead = 0;

    _portAvailable = NO;
  } else {
    _portAvailable = YES;
  }
}

- (void)readBytesAvailable:(UInt32)length {
  if ( ! _data ) {
    // Here no one's interested in received data
    // So you can decide if you want to save them for later use or trash them
    // We are going to trash them
    [_rscMgr read:_buffer length:MIN( BUFFER_SIZE, length )];
    return;
  }

  UInt32 bytesToRead;

  // First of all, we can't read more than our buffer size
  bytesToRead = MIN( BUFFER_SIZE, length );

  // Also it's enough to read only what user requested
  UInt32 remainingBytes = _totalBytesToRead - _data.length;
  bytesToRead = MIN( bytesToRead, remainingBytes );

  // Now read bytes
  UInt32 bytesRead = [_rscMgr read:_buffer length:bytesToRead];
  if ( bytesRead > 0 ) {
    [_data appendBytes:_buffer length:bytesRead];
  }

  if ( _data.length == _totalBytesToRead ) {
    if ( _successBlock ) {
      _successBlock( _data );
    }

    _successBlock = nil;
    _failureBlock = nil;
    _data = nil;
    _totalBytesToRead = 0;
  }
}

@end
```

**Serial Port Usage**

And here's how would I use my class.

```
#import "SerialPortUser.h"
#import "SerialPortCommunication.h"

@interface SerialPortUser() {
  SerialPortCommunication *_serial;
}

@end

@implementation SerialPortUser

- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if ( self ) {
    _serial = [[SerialPortCommunication alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)getData {
  [_serial readBytes:81
             success:^(NSData *data) {
               // Here you have NSData with 81 bytes for sure
             }
             failure:^(NSData *dataReadSoFar, NSError *error) {
               // Here you have NSData with dataReadSoFar.length bytes only
               // read so far, because an error happens
               // And error is in NSError *error
             }];
}

@end
```